# Как открыть свое приложение с помощью Siri?

Tags: ios, swift

Что нужно сделать в приложении, чтобы его можно было открывать, сказав:

> Привет, Сири. Открой [названиеПриложения (или)
>   другойВариантНазванияПриложения]

Допустим, есть игра крестики-нолики, у которой название (под иконкой "XO"). Если произнести:

> Сири, открой приложение иксОу

То она его откроет.

Как добавить некий алиас, чтобы Сири открывала приложение и по фразе:

> Сири, открой приложение крестики-нолики

Comment: возможно [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47801734/2881286) поможет?

Answer (score 1):

Верно, на хабре статья за июнь 16 года

(iOS 10) Встраиваем поддержку Siri в свое iOS приложение

Смысл в работе с Xcode 8, загрузкой для проекта в нем библиотеки CoreLocation.framework и написании функций, обучении своего приложения взаимодействию с Siri. Статья большая, подробная но понятная, рекомендую прочитать, здесь все не распишешь.

https://habr.com/post/303316/

Comment: Ссылку бы хоть оставили

Comment: вуаля! https://habr.com/post/303316/

Answer (score 0):

Для этого надо использовать библиотеку CoreLocation.framework. Есть старенькая [статья](https://habr.com/post/303316/) на хабре по этому поводу)